# URL on Lightning Datatable with search function is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

URL on a field on my lightning datatable Component used to be working. When I add a search function I get the error as

> 'Action failed: c:test_filterComponent$controller$doInit [component is not defined]'

My controller

```
({
doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
     // {label: 'Trainee Name', fieldName: 'Trainee__c', type: 'text',initialWidth: 300, cellAttributes: {alignment: 'left'},sortable: true},
       
      {label: 'Trainee Name', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Trainee__c' }, initialWidth: 300,sortable: true}}, 
        {label: 'Field', fieldName: 'Workplace__c', type: 'text',initialWidth: 300, cellAttributes: {alignment: 'left'},sortable: true},
        {label: 'Department', fieldName: 'NZ_Ski_Dept_2021__c', type: 'text', initialWidth: 300, cellAttributes: {alignment: 'left'}, sortable: true},
        {label: 'Online', fieldName: 'NZSki_Induction_2021_Online_Mod_Format__c', type: 'text', cellAttributes: {alignment: 'center'},initialWidth: 100, sortable: true},
        {label: 'Standards', fieldName: 'NZSki_Induction_Mod_Format__c', type: 'text', cellAttributes: {alignment: 'center'}, initialWidth: 100, sortable: true}
        
    ]);
            
     var action = component.get("c.getTPlans");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var records =response.getReturnValue();
        records.forEach(function(record){
            // record['linkName'] = 'https://skillsactiveaotearoa.force.com/nzski3/s/detail/'+ record.TraineeRef__c;
            record['linkName'] = 'https://preprod-skillsactiveaotearoa.cs197.force.com/nzski3/s/detail/'+ record.TraineeRef__c;
        });
        component.set("v.mydata", records);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    
    var actionFilter = {"field":cmp.get("v.field"),"dept":cmp.get("v.dept")};
    helper.getData(cmp, actionFilter);
},


doSearch:function(cmp, event, helper){
    var actionFilter = {"field":cmp.get("v.field"),"dept":cmp.get("v.dept")};
    helper.getData(cmp, actionFilter);
},

updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
    cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
    helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
}
```

})

Helper

```
({
getData : function(cmp, actionFilter) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.getTPlans');
    action.setParams(actionFilter)
    action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set('v.mydata', response.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
        }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
sortData: function (cmp, fieldName, sortDirection) {
    var data = cmp.get("v.mydata");
    var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
    //sorts the rows based on the column header that's clicked
    data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
    cmp.set("v.mydata", data);
},
sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = primer ?
        function(x) {return primer(x[field])} :
        function(x) {return x[field]};
    //checks if the two rows should switch places
    reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    }
}
```

})

Can someone help to find where I wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple copy-paste error to me.

Your function has a variable `cmp` and not `component` and hence all you need is to make sure you use `cmp`

```
var action = cmp.get("c.getTPlans");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var records =response.getReturnValue();
    records.forEach(function(record){
        // record['linkName'] = 'https://skillsactiveaotearoa.force.com/nzski3/s/detail/'+ record.TraineeRef__c;
        record['linkName'] = 'https://preprod-skillsactiveaotearoa.cs197.force.com/nzski3/s/detail/'+ record.TraineeRef__c;
    });
    cmp.set("v.mydata", records);
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was an silly mistake

Comment: Values on link field can be seen only when initiating the page. After searching the results comes without values in link field. Is something wrong ?

Comment: Sorry you will need to post a new query highlighting the exact problem!